Is there a function to compare character columns?
I am fairly new to R, and I am trying to compare two character columns.
I have a file with two columns and 5000+ rows of species names. The columns are different lengths, and many species names are repeated.
Column 1 (Bee) is an old list of species. Column 2 (scientificName) is the updated list of species. I need to measure the size of each species, so I want the updated list to have every species from both columns, once.
I need more than just "equal" or "not equal"; I need to see what species are missing from each column compared to the other. Essentially, I need each column to be a list of only unique species (not repeats) and to see if either column has species the other does not (I hope I am articulating that clearly).
I used the unique() function initially to get a list of names without repetition. I was then going to compare the lists for each column, but the output is not in a format that is easily transferred manually to a .csv. (It lists 1 "species name" 2 "species name" etc. and I need each species in a row without numbers or quotations).
Most of the code I've found is only applicable to numerical data.
I've since tried the following:
df %>%    mutate(comparison = if_else(     as.character(df$Bees) == as.character(df$scientificName), "equal", "different"))
I got an error: 'Comparison' must be size 5386 or 1, not 0.
-----
df$Match <- as.character(df$Bees) == as.character(df$scientificName)
Here the error says:
Error in $<-: ! Assigned data as.character(df$Bees) == as.character(df$scientificName)must be compatible with existing data. ✖ Existing data has 5386 rows. ✖ Assigned data has 0 rows. ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled. Caused by error invectbl_recycle_rhs_rows(): ! Can't recycle input of size 0 to size 5386.
-----
library(vecsets) eg_data <- data.frame(   col1 = df$Bee,   col2 = df$scientificName,   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)  eg_data$name1_diff1_2 <- mapply(vsetdiff, strsplit(eg_data$col1, split = ""),  strsplit(eg_data$col2, split = "")) eg_data$name2_diff2_1 <- mapply(vsetdiff, strsplit(eg_data$col2, split = ""),  strsplit(eg_data$col1, split = ""))
The output for this has each character as it's own string.
-----
setdiff(df$Bee, df$scientificName)
This output was the closest I got, it does show the different species, but it doesn't tell me where that difference is (i.e. which column has it and which one doesn't)
-----
anti_join(df$Bee, df$scientificName, by = "text")
The error message was
Error in UseMethod("anti_join") :    no applicable method for 'anti_join' applied to an object of class "character"

EDIT: Apologies, I forgot to post an example of my data. A few rows of my excel file are as follows (I'm not sure how to post tables. As new as I am to R, I am even newer to Stack Overflow haha):
 scientificName           Bee
   Trigona fulviventris   Trigona fulviventris
   Trigona fulviventris   Trigona fulviventris
   Trigona fulviventris   Trigona corvina
   Apis mellifera         Ceratina buscki
   Centris varia          Scaura argyrea
   Tetragonisca angustula

So I would like output that tells me that the unique names in "Bee" are Trigona fulviventris, T. corvina, Ceratina buscki, and Scaura argyrea. As well as the new unique names in "scientificName", so just Apis mellifera and Centris varia. The end goal is to make a list that says "Trigona fulviventris, T. corvina, Apis mellifera, Ceratina buscki, Centris varia, Scaura argyrea, Tetragonisca angustula". I just want to know what new names need to be added to my overall list without having to scroll through 5000 repeats.
I can always go back to the unique() function, get a list for each column, paste them into excel without quotations or numbers, and then compare. I am just hoping there is an easier way to do it.
Thank you!

If I get it correctly, you can do a join by creating two tables with the same data. If you need non-exact match, you can use fuzzy join. otherwise dplyr join will be enough

It's going to be difficult to give a precise answer without a minimal reproducible example that reflects the core problem. Try to generate a small scenario that can easily be posted e.g. dput(small_df1).

The command df$Match <- as.character(df$Bees) == as.character(df$scientificName) is asking R to perform a comparison of the two values. The result of the == operator is always a logical vector, but it looks like the output of your call is length 0 (perhaps NULL?). So it can't recycle the vector across nrow(df). Rerun as:
x <- as.character(df$Bees) == as.character(df$scientificName)

and give us the resulting error if any.

Thank you! I think I can do this once I get a list of unique names to start with. Because there are repeats and the columns aren't the same length, I get a lot of NA values.

If this is your data (as mentioned in the comments you can always use dput to post your own real data frame)
dput(df)
structure(list(scientificName = c("Trigona fulviventris", "Trigona fulviventris", 
"Trigona fulviventris", "Apis mellifera", "Centris varia", "Tetragonisca angustula"
), Bee = c("Trigona fulviventris", "Trigona fulviventris", "Trigona corvina", 
"Ceratina buscki", "Scaura argyrea", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

df
          scientificName                  Bee
1   Trigona fulviventris Trigona fulviventris
2   Trigona fulviventris Trigona fulviventris
3   Trigona fulviventris      Trigona corvina
4         Apis mellifera      Ceratina buscki
5          Centris varia       Scaura argyrea
6 Tetragonisca angustula                 <NA>

Using merge on both columns might give you the output you want
merge(data.frame(a = unique(df$Bee), "Bee"), 
      data.frame(a = unique(df$scientificName), "scientificName"), all=T)
                       a X.Bee. X.scientificName.
1         Apis mellifera   <NA>    scientificName
2          Centris varia   <NA>    scientificName
3        Ceratina buscki    Bee              <NA>
4         Scaura argyrea    Bee              <NA>
5 Tetragonisca angustula   <NA>    scientificName
6        Trigona corvina    Bee              <NA>
7   Trigona fulviventris    Bee    scientificName
8                   <NA>    Bee              <NA>

